# Updating a table on DB considering changes on a grid in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable, sql-update, odp.net

I'm filling a `Data Grid` in C# (WinForms) via a `System.Data.DataTable`. `DataTable` is filled from a `DB table` via `ODP`.

I have a `data navigator` in `Data Grid` for updating, deleting and inserting rows.

I want to use `DataTable` to commit all changes made in `Data Grid` to the database.

I have to use `OracleDataAdapter` but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

What kind of a `CommandText` should I use to achieve all three commands (`update`, `delete`, `insert`)?

The code below didn't work (maybe because `CommandText` I inserted is not appropriate)

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, OracleCommand oracleCommand, CommandType commandType, DataTable dataTable)
{
        oracleCommand.CommandText = commandText;
        oracleCommand.CommandType = commandType;

        try
        {
            oracleCommand.Connection = m_Connection;
            OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);
            oracleDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LoggerTrace.Instance.Write(TraceEventType.Error, LoggerTrace.LoggerTraceSource.DatabaseManagerError, "Query could not be executed!");
            throw;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OracleCommandBuilder` producess the appropriate `insert`, `update` and `delete` queries after the `select` query is inserted.

```
string selectCommand = "select * from Table";
oracleDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(selectCommand, m_Connection);
OracleCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(oracleDataAdapter);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

After `OracleCommandBuilder` build the command this way you can execute any updates in the `DataTable` like this:

```
oracleDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

Sequences, virtual columns etc. are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

for insert create a new row in data table and insert into data table ,for update update the value and finally make save change of data set or data table

Comment: Yes but what will be the `CommandText` like and i wonder if my `#ExecuteNonQuery(...)` method is correct for this purpose?